# Is the adjective "cheap" used to convey an opinion or a fact?

Tags: adjectives, word-order

I'm taking an online English Grammar course, and I'm a little bit confused with the adjectives order thing.

In the course is said that the order is:

1. Opinion (nice, lovely, ugly, terrible)
2. Size (big, small, enormous, tiny)
3. Age (old, new, 12-year-old, ancient)
4. Shape (square, oval, round)
5. Color (blue, red, golden, spotted)
6. Origin (Italian, European, American)
7. Material (wooden, gold, silk)
8. Use (dinner – dinner table, flower – flower pot)

So, in the phrase:

> A RIDICULOUS CHEAP PLASTIC toy

To me, it seems that *ridiculous* and *cheap* "opinion" adjectives, so why does *ridiculous* go first?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your question may be a duplicate of [What is the rule for adjective order?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order)

Comment: I want to say ***ridiculously cheap***. But whether one says *ridiculous* or *ridiculously* is dependent on meaning. Do you mean the toy was ridiculous, or was it the cheapness that was ridiculous? If it is the latter you need the adverb *...ly*.

Comment: Hi choster! There are pretty good answers covering the rules of ordering adjectives. I know the rules, but I'm looking for a very specific explanation. Thank you!

Comment: *Ridiculous* is an opinion, it means silly, stupid, and foolish. *Cheap* can also be an opinion, expressing one's low opinion of something, but in your sentence (without further context) it's clearly a fact because plastic tends to be cheap (low price), and plastic toys tend to be cheaper than ones made from wood, for example.

Comment: @WS2 I was not given any context...

Comment: I thought "cheap" was going first in this sentence, as "cheap" and "ridiculous" are both opinion adjectives but "cheap" is more common...

Comment: May I suggest that you modify the title? *Is the adjective "cheap" an opinion or a fact?* That would explain your confusion, because as your question is currently titled, it seems you want to know *in which order* you should place the adjectives.

Comment: Because I wanted to say ridiculous**ly**, *ridiculous cheap plastic toy* sounded more intuitive, but when I suppressed that urge, and considered the adjectival alternatives, *cheap ridiculous plastic toy* sounded just as good to my ear, suggesting that both *cheap* and *ridiculous* could be considered a matter of opinion, just like this question!

Comment: You'd certainly use _a lousy two-dollar cigar_ rather than _a two-dollar lousy cigar_, where the uncertainty about the price/value-descriptor is removed. But the 'royal order' is just a (pretty good) rule of thumb. Have a look at different versions of the rule at the original post (be careful; Swan confuses adjectives and determiners. But the article is good apart from that.) Another is given in [this Wordwizard article](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=24803&p=89441&hilit=royal+order+adjectives#p89441), & Phil White points out that the 'order' does not hold rigorously.

Comment: ... ... I'm cheating a bit with 'two-dollar' as it's not in adjectival _form_. Other lists substitute the broader 'observation' for 'opinion'; this clearly covers both 'ridiculous' and 'cheap' (though a comma wouldn't normally be inserted between them, and the reverse order wouldn't be used). Both 'ridiculous' and 'cheap' would usually be placed before say 'little'.  Complicated.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I think that, although my answer was marked as wrong by the online grading tool, it wouldn't sound "weird" if I ever have to say it in a conversation... Am I right?

Comment: There's no defined order for *cheap* and *ridiculous* here.  It does sound a little better with *cheap* first, though to be honest, it sounds like an unlikely adjective pile either way.

Comment: Ridiculous cheap little old online grading tool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cheap" can be a statement of fact or an opinion.  "Coke is on sale for 99 cents for a two-liter bottle.  That's cheap." = That's a great discount, not that Coke is a shoddy product.
"The child got a cheap toy with his Happy Meal, and it broke in a half hour." = The toy was not well-made and as such, fell apart fast.

Usually, context will make this clear.  If context does not clarify, recast the sentence:  "The diamond ring was inexpensive/a great buy/a steal/a bargain/worth more than I paid."  And for the other sense, "shoddy" or "cheaply made" clarifies.

Comment: Sorry if I sound silly, but I'm afraid I'm still confused: If I took "Cheap" as a statement of fact, how would I order the adjectives in the phrase "A RIDICULOUS CHEAP PLASTIC toy"? And if I took it as an opinion, why would "A CHEAP RIDICULOUS PLASTIC toy" be wrong? Thank you for your patience!

Comment: With either sense of the word, it seems the sense of the expression requires the adverb "ridiculously" (before "cheap.")  Either the item is ridiculously inexpensive, or of ridiculously low quality.  Otherwise, it's not clear what you mean--"ridiculous" means "to be laughed at," so what are you laughing at?  I imagine it is the cheapness of the item, not the item itself.

Comment: Thank you! Reading all this, I think that a "A RIDICULOUS CHEAP PLASTIC toy" it's a simply a bad example to practice the order of adjectives...

Comment: No, it's not a bad example at all. Both "cheap" and "ridiculous" are matters of opinion. One man's bargain (or junk) may be too expensive (or good enough) for another man. And one man may ridicule what another man admires. The question is, how do you handle it when both adjectives are of the same priority?  One way is to use a comma: "A cheap, ridiculous toy" OR "A ridiculous, cheap toy", depending which aspect you want to emphasize more.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought: they are two adjectives of the same priority, I don't know which one has more emphasis -because I have been given no context- so I'll put the most common one first. But the grading tool marked "a cheap ridiculous cheap plastic toy" as wrong... >__<